# Confusion about variables equaling functions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, function-calls, function-parameter

I have these functions:

```
function change(num1, num2){
    //return number
}

function getFunction(funct){
    //return function
}
```

this declaration:

```
var funct = getFunction(change);
```

and this call

```
funct(array);
```

I am confused about what the call does. Where does it send `array`, what exactly is it doing? I just can't wrap my head around it. When sending the function `change()` into `getFunction()` what exactly does this do and again how does JS handle `funct(array)`? Let me know if I need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFunction` returns a function.

```
var funct = getFunction(change);
```

`funct` is now assigned to the returned function reference

`funct(array)` is just calling the function returned from the previous assignment.

Comment: ok so just to clarify, since funct is defined as a function that returns a function, this now makes funct a callable function?

Comment: `funct` is not a defined function. It's a variable that a function was assigned to

Comment: so when you call `funct(array)`. `array` is being sent into the function that is returned by `getFunction(change)`?